# git: jump back again during interactive rebase

Tags: git

is there a trick to go back again during an interactive git rebase? Let's say something like this:

```
git init

for c in a b c; do
    touch $c && git add $c && git commit -m $c
done
```

Now let's say I start some interactive rebase like this:

```
git rebase -i --root
# p 5e2df3f a
# e b87116d b
# p a55558f c
```

And, after editing `b` to my likings - maybe by splitting it into two commits after a `git reset HEAD^ -p`, I end up with:

```
git commit --amend
touch b2 && git add b2 git commit -m "b''"
git log --oneline 
# a5f42cc (HEAD) b''
# 5446996 b'
# 5e2df3f a
```

how can I now jump *back* without first having to finish the rebase up until the end? I.e. right at this stage I would see:

```
git rebase --edit-todo
# p a55558f c
```

But what if I made a mistake in my new `5446996 b'` commit? What if I realize I have to amend something else in `5e2df3f a` that was originally the start of my rebase edit todo?

Can I somehow jump back - like a nested `git rebase -i` (which isn't allowed directly)? Or is there some other means to achieve this?

I explicitly do *not* want to have to finish the rebase I'm in and then restart it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just replay manually what a nested rebase would do. That is, you can just go back to the commit and fix it up:

```
git checkout 5446996
# edit
git commit -a --amend
```

Then you cherry-pick the remaining commit(s):

```
git cherry-pick 5446996..a5f42cc
```

If necessary, fixup conflicts and `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Then finish your rebase with `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: thank you! I'll try to put this into a somewhat more automated script to make it less of a hassle to jump back. I think instead of the git cherry-pick, one could essentially add the commit range into the edit-todo after the checkout!

Comment: Thanks, this is really great! I automated it all via https://github.com/milianw/shell-helpers/blob/master/git-fixup now, let's see how it will behave in the real world over the next weeks :)